# can't start my Windows 10 computer from a memory stick

Tags: boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I am trying to install Kubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Windows 10 Home Single Language, which is brand-new. My machine is ASUS, the specifications:
Intel(R) core(TM) i7‎‎-‎9750‎H 2.60 GHz,
RAM: 16 GB,
512 GB SSD PCIe NVMe M.2‎

I have been closely following these instructions in the same order (No CD drives, so I used a 16GB USB stick) :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation,
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#10-installation-complete,
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

I used Windows Disk Management and gave Ubuntu 100 gigabytes (I wonder if I can change this to the previous number if I cannot install Linux).
when I got to the part where I start it from a memory stick (the third link), I just couldn't do it. Whenever I restart the machine, it boots into Windows. I tried to test if the computer can boot from USB, I couldn't do it. I just didn't know how to do it, because when I downloaded, extracted and ran Memtest86+ USB Installer, and restarted the computer, nothing happened. Kubuntu wasn't erased from the memory stick.

One thing I did, which I didn't do before because I thought I don't need to do it if I'm not using LiveDVD, seemed promising. I tried to change the boot order in the UEFI editor, when I chose the option Kubuntu instead of Windows 10, the computer restarted and showed a bluish logo Kubuntu. At this point I thought I was going to install it, but the next screen showed installation of "something" at 1%, shortly after the computer shut down. When I turn it on again, Windows shows up again.

I'm obviously new to this.

What should I do?

Hello again. I apologize I haven't used this platform before. At any rate, I used winmd5 to check the integrity and the files are correct. I also used Etcher to write the to USB. I still cannot install it.

UPDATE:

I managed to fix the problem by going to EFI Firmware settings and then clicking on "Start Kubuntu (Sage Graphics)" instead of "Start Kubuntu"

Comment: @Amansa Levi, do you have Legacy or UEFI mode in your BIOS?

Comment: Nmath, I hope I'm understanding correctly, I was following the instructions and that's why I shrank C. I didn't verify the integrity because I'm not using a CD and I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: Nadndete82, I'm ashamed to say I don't know and don't know how to check, but I presume it's UEFI because that's what I saw when I was editing it.

Comment: @Nmath I'm certain it's neither corrupted nor written incorrectly. I downloaded it from the official website and wrote it in accordance with the instructions.